# User Certificate is Null in HTTPServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, ssl, x509certificate, weblogic-10.x

I am running a servlet in Weblogic 10.3 with two-way SSL enabled. When I try to get the following attributes from the HTTPServletRequest, both are null:

```
- javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate
- weblogic.servlet.request.SSLSession
```

How then do I access the user's certificate from the servlet? I have searched online with no luck.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the connection is working over SSL and the user certificate is definitely being sent from the browser to Weblogic.

Comment: Does the page require confidentiality?

Comment: Any sign of errors in the server logs? I know with JBoss you often have to also change the config to get the security related logging.

Comment: Did you configure WLS to require authentication by using the auth.xml policy file that ships with WLS?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at how your keystore is set up.  From my experience, this kind of error can occur if the user's or server's signed certificate isn't imported into the keystore correctly.

To verify this, run keytool on your keystore to determine which alias in the keystore contains a private key.  Then, take a look at that alias and see if it has the signed (approved) certificate associated with it, or if the signed certificate has another alias associated with it.

This kind of error is common when using applications which will only look for a specific alias in your keystore for validation. Normally this is configurable so that you can ensure that your certificates all have unique "names" in the certificate.  It is common, for example, to use a linux box' hostname in the certificate name, and then to create an alias that is the hostname.